# Continuity and its definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Is it true that a function $f$ is continuous at point $a$ if the following holds?
>   $$
> \exists\varepsilon > 0 \ \ \ \exists\delta>0 \text{ such that }\ \ 
>  |x - a|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}| < \varepsilon
> $$

I know that this is easily solved when we use the limit definition of derivatives, but can it be solved without using derivatives?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lipschitz continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395211/lipschitz-continuous)

Comment: No.  Your conclusion does not rule out  $$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}< -100$$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I doubt that's a duplicate of the question you linked. This question is about proving that Lipschitz continuity implies continuity, which is not discussed in the question you linked.

Comment: You must exclude $x=a$. That is, $0 < |x - a|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}| < \varepsilon$. It means that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ with $f'(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. In the younterval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, you have$$\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(a)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\varepsilon\lvert x-a\rvert.$$Therefore, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)-f(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$$

it is continuous at $x=0$ but

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ is not bounded near $0$.

Comment: The OP wrote “if”, not “only if”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If it is differentiable, it is necessarily continuous.

Comment: Your comment in no way adresses the point that I raised.