# An ODE with maximum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation has unic solution? :

$$y^{´}(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{@{} l c @{}}
     \text{max}\{t,y(t)\}\\
      y(0)=0 
    \end{array}\right.$$

where $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

My idea was to separate in cases, when :

$$ y(t)\leq t \implies y^{´}(t)=t \implies dy = t dt   $$ or

$$ y(t)>t \implies y^{´}(t)=y(t) \implies \dfrac{dy}{y} = dt$$

But I do not know how to guarantee the uniqueness. Thanks for read!

Comment: Could you apply the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)? The only non-trivial part is to check that the max is Lipschitz in $y$, however, it is [doable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395211/lipschitz-continuous).

Comment: Yes, that was another of my ideas. To apply the aforementioned theorem, we need to see that it is lipchitz with respect to the second variable. Now, I check your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You get solutions $y=Ae^t$ and $y=B+\dfrac{t^2}2$

Note that the initial condition $y(0)=0$ kills the exponential in the neighbourhood of zero, so we are left with $y=\dfrac{t^2}2$.

But as you can see on the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xo4ehaicbq

This solution in only valid for $t\in[0,2]$ (we need $y(t)\le t$), outside this interval, it should be the exponential solution.

So you will have a piecewise solution $\begin{cases} y=0 & y\le 0\\ y=\frac {t^2}2 & y\in[0,2]\\ y=Ae^t & y\ge 2\end{cases}$

But for the solution to be $C^1$ we need $y'(2)=t\bigg|_{t=2}=Ae^t\bigg|_{t=2}\iff A=\frac 2{e^2}\approx 0.27$

Comment: Thanks :) and it´s unic?

Comment: Well do you have other choice for gluing the pieces in terms of $A_{<0}$, $A_{>2}$ and $B$ ? It seems to me they are uniquely determined. What do you think ? The solution is unique if there is no other triplet that gives a valid solution.